# SPFx Extension - modern experience for search results.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-search, spfx-extensions

I want to create a header in a modern site page. The header will have SharePoint search (similar to communication sites).

After clicking on search, we will be landed on results.aspx page. Now in this page we have webparts of search box, search refiners, results etc., but the problem is this seems to be classic page where i need to bring in modern experience for this too.

I am aware of how to create a header and search with a search button but how to modernize the results page with SPFx extension.

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharePoint PnP group has been working hard to provide tools to modernize your classic pages.

I know it is not using an SPFX extension.

Right now PowerShell and .Net are the only ways to convert the pages, though a UI option is in Beta now.

you might convert the page and then add your header.

Take a look here:
[Transform classic pages to modern client-side pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-site-pages)

Comment: Glad to help.  The SharePoint Patterns and Practices community is really doing some great work.